# how to convert MOD video file without loosing quality to modern popular format for TV

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have MOD video file. My LG TV doesn't support MOD.
How can I convert MOD video file without loosing quality to modern video format to watch it on different modern TVs?

Comment: Simply changing the file extension to `.mpg` can work with some players, although the aspect ratio may be incorrect. Have you tried the ffmpeg / avconv command line suggested in the Wikipedia page on [MOD and TOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOD_and_TOD)?

Comment: I see this wiki page, but I am not sure what parameters I should set to don't loosing quality. For example I must set bitrate. What else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typical video file is a container for video data. The video data itself is compressed by some codec. You therefore have to distinguish between the *container* format and the *video codec*.
For a correct answer you should tell the codec type of the video data in your file. You find lots of information about your video file by

```
ffprobe yourfile.MOD
```

If the codec is one that is understood by your TV, you can repack your video data into another container format with

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile.MOD -c:copy out.mp4
```

Or whatever container format you desire. On the other hand if the codec of the MOD file is not understood, you must recode your video data which necessarily incurs losses on the video quality. For that case refer to any tutorial about transcoding.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have not ffmpeg on my ubuntu 14.04, but I had found avprobe and avconf and used it.

    avprobe MOV14C.MOD;
    avconv -i MOV14C.MOD -codec copy MOV14C.MP4